# Can't run website from server (C:\inetpub\www) by its name (www.slid.com.ph)

Tags: dns, website

I have a problem when I run our website through browser.

It gives me the following error:

http://www.slid.com.ph

This site can’t be reached

www.slid.com.ph’s server DNS address could not be found.

What could be the problem?

Result of `nslookup`:

```
C:\Users\services>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::1

> sliddc
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::1

*** UnKnown can't find sliddc: Query refused
```

Comment: You appear to have no DNS servers configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this website to be available on the Internet, you must make sure there are valid DNS entries for the domain and that a webserver is listening on http (80) and/or https (443) ports.

I can see domain www.slid.com.ph points to ip `122.3.138.42`, that port 443 is open and that there is a IIS7 webserver listening on it and serving a default webpage.

You seem to stop at DNS resolution, therefore I would like to suggest you make sure you have valid DNS servers setup on your client. I believe you should see a different line than `Default Server:  UnKnown`.

also, you should query for `www.slid.com.ph` instead of `sliddc`.

Lastly, I would change the link you provide from http://www.slid.com.ph to https://www.slid.com.ph because nothing is listening on http port (80). Unless you want to also serve http, in which case you should configure IIS to do so and make sure port 80 is open on your firewall.

---

**Update:** after 14 days, you comment this answer asking for what to do.

First of all, the situation has changed: ip `122.3.138.42` no longer responds to ping nor http on port `443` anymore.

**What to do, client side** is making sure you are using a client with a working Internet connection and properly setup nameservers. Use Google's `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` if in doubt. When thing are setup correctly, you should get:

```
>nslookup www.slid.com.ph
Server:         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.slid.com.ph canonical name = slid.com.ph.
Name:   slid.com.ph
Address: 122.3.138.42
```

**What to do, on the server**:

1. make sure the server is reachable at ip `122.3.138.42` on either port `80` for http, port `443` for https, or both. I would also recommend allowing ICMP ping. This means setting up a server and allowing incoming traffic on the firewall.
2. configure your webserver software (it seems you want to use IIS) to listen on either port `80` or `443` or both, and serve your contents. A common setup is to redirect http requests on port `80` to https on port `443`.

Comment: so... what should I do first? Sorry, I am newbie. Our domain www.slid.com.ph points to what IP instead? @simlev